# Imagick equivalent to imagemagick command for merging images with transparency

Tags: php, imagemagick, imagick

imagemagick: 
convert image1.png image2.png -background transparent image3.png   image4.png -layers flatten new.png

works. 
Basically, it merges 4 png's as layers, image2 is the biggest, all png's have transparency.

I can't find any equivalent commands in Imagick.

Comment: Have you tried [appendimages](http://php.net/manual/en/imagick.appendimages.php)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like this:

```
#!/usr/local/bin/php
<?php

    $i1 = new Imagick("1.png"); 
    $i2 = new Imagick("2.png"); 

    $i1->compositeImage($i2,Imagick::COMPOSITE_DEFAULT,0,0); 
    $i1->writeImage('result.png');

    // Flatten those puppies - if required
    $i1->flattenImages(); 
    $i1->writeImage('result_flat.png');
?>
```

If I create the images like this:

```
# Red -> transparent gradient
convert -size 128x128 gradient:"rgba(255,0,0,0)-rgba(255,0,0,1)" 1.png
```

[image]

```
# Blue -> transparent gradient
convert -size 128x128 gradient:"rgba(0,0,255,0)-rgba(0,0,255,1)" -rotate 90 2.png
```

[image]

I can then merge them with the above code and I get this:

[image]